# Give expected spoken to dialogflow, so it can try to fit answer with that

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building a learning bot. The bot is asking the user to say a special sentence:

Bot: Please repeat: 'I have to say this.'
    User: i have to say this

I have an array of expected answers. If one of them matches the spoken, it getting a proved result.
the query is getting lowercased and gets minor equalisations fixes like replaced '.', '?' etc.

So if dialogflow understands the user right, my proof functions works fine.

```
expectedAnswers.forEach((answer) => {
    if (userQuery === answer) isCorrect = true;
});
```

My problem: often dialogflow's interpretation of spoken differs completely from what user said.

'does he' -> 'darcy' for instance.

More frustrating: The Google Actions simulator, is getting it right first, but switches to wrong variation at the end. (Because there is no context, I know it is hard to be smart without that.)

So my idea is, to give dialogflow a hint what it should expect. So that if it tries to find correct understood spoken, it can compare it with the expected phrase.

Any idea how to solve this? I can't figure out the right searching terms for google, so I need your help please.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to determine what a user said and match it to an expected input is actually one of the main purposes of natural language understanding systems like Dialogflow. I think the issue is with the way you're architecting your solution.

> So my idea is, to give dialogflow a hint what it should expect. So
>   that if it tries to find correct understood spoken, it can compare it
>   with the expected phrase.

The way that you give Dialogflow hints as to what you expect a user to say is [via the training phrases for an intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#training-phrases). Rather than trying to exact match on transcribed user input, which is going to cause many of the problems Dialogflow is attempting to solve, let Dialogflow determine if the user answered correctly.

You can do this with an intent structure like the following:

`Welcome (Do you want to take a quiz?)
├- no
└- yes 
   ├- correct answers
   └- incorrect (default follow-up fallback)`

From the intent that starts the quiz, you can create [follow-up intents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#follow-up_intents) for each of the correct answers, and use a default fallback follow-up intent for any incorrect answers. Use the training phrases of the follow-up intents to train on the expected correct answers.

[I built an agent which you can import into your account](http://share.voxable.io/0Q2c0n3m3s2V/download/StackOverflowExample.zip) that demonstrates the above. Here's an example of it in action:

[image: trivia agent example]

Despite the fact that I didn't train on "a door, I think" specifically in my intent, Dialogflow was still able to match it to the example answers I did provide.

You can also check out [the example trivia agent from the Dialogflow team](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-temperature-converter-nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

That is not the issue of Dialogflow or Action-on-Google. This is happening because Speech to Text conversion is failing. If you are not a regular user with the device you are interacting to or you use less of it for Speech conversation, then it will not learn your way of speaking and may produce different results. Also, try to set the language of the device as per your region or dialect. Accent also play role in Speech to Text to be successful.

The more you interact with the device using the same Google account the more it will understand you correctly. Do not share the device and Google account with others as that will not help in learning and Speech to Text conversion.